# List view hide in emulator

Tags: android-studio, listview

I try to write a to-do list app using `ListView`. But there is a problem when I use the keyboard on my phone and try to add something to the list the first elements are not visible. After I add 3 or 4 elements, I am able to see the to-do list items. How I can adjust the listview that it won't go up when I use the keyboard.

Here is the XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.403" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Click to add..."
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you shear the XML files that you are using. To get he better idea of the problem.

Comment: I added already. Thanks in advance for your help